# Replace multiple columns with years for one column

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I'm working with worldbank data and I'm trying to create some graphs representing time, but the data I have now looks like this:

[image]

As I don't think there's a way to change it to a datetime I think the only way is to replace all these years columns with 1 column called 'Year' with column names I have right now as values and current values in a separate column.

Is there any nice function in Python that allows that or would I have to iterate through the entire dataframe?

Edit to include some code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country Name': ['Aruba', 'Afghanistan', 'Angola'],
   'Country Code': ['ABW', 'AFG', 'AGO'],
   '1960':[65.66, 32.29, 33.25],
   '1961': [66.07, 32.74, 33.57],
   '1962': [66.44, 33.18, 33.91], 
   '1963': [66.79, 33.62, 34.27], 
   '1964': [66.11, 34.06, 34.65], 
   '1965': [67.44, 34.49, 35.03]}).set_index('Country Name')
```

Comment: You shouldn't post code as a picture. You want to make it easy to copy for those who will attempt to find your solution.

Comment: I do realise it's not easy to copy it but I was hoping for someone to point me in the right direction, not necessarily give me a ready code. But if it's required, I'll post the code.

Comment: Right, but often people will need to test out the solution they provide to you and don't want to manually write out your dataset.

Comment: @n8_ edited as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can try taking transpose of the dataframe thus the year values will become rows and then you can rename this as year and use it in the plots.

You can try something like this :

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country Name' : ['Aruba', 'Afghanistan', 'Angola'],
   'Country Code' : ['ABW', 'AFG', 'AGO'],
   '1960' : [65.66, 32.29, 33.25],
   '1961' : [66.07, 32.74, 33.57],
   '1962' : [66.44, 33.18, 33.91], 
   '1963' : [66.79, 33.62, 34.27], 
   '1964' : [66.11, 34.06, 34.65], 
   '1965' : [67.44, 34.49, 35.03]})

df2 = df1.transpose()
df2.columns = df1['Country Name']
df2 = df2[2:]
df2['Year'] = df2.index.values

plt.plot(df2['Year'], df2['Aruba'])
plt.plot(df2['Year'], df2['Afghanistan'])
plt.plot(df2['Year'], df2['Angola'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output : [Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXUPf.png)

Comment: That gives me country in columns - I was hoping to keep all countries in one column.

Comment: All the country values are in one column in the original dataframe but year values are separate columns and to plot year wise better keep the years in one columns and countries in separate columns. You got less values for country than year so it will be easy to plot countries separately by year.
Im not sure what kind of graph you are trying to make with this data ?